# Reimplementing algorithm from GPL program

Tags: licensing, gpl

If I reimplement an algorithm of a program covered by GPL v2 do I have to also license my program as GPL v2?

And to be specific:

I need a javascript library to compare debian packages versions. There is no such. So I'm going to directly translate the comparison algorithm implemented in `apt` (C++) into JS and publish it thereafter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are literally translating the C++ code that implements the algorithm, then you are creating a derived work of `apt` and you must license your code under the GPL as well.

On the other hand, if you implement the algorithm based on a textual/mathematical description of the algorithm without looking at the C++ implementation, then your code is *not* a derived work and you are free to choose your license as you wish.

If you don't translate the C++ code, but you do look at it, then you are in a legal grey area. In that case, it is not entirely clear if your code will be considered a derived work or an independent implementation of the algorithm. To be on the safe side, you can best regard it as a derived work.

The difference exists because algorithms themselves are not subject to copyright, but their implementations are.

Comment: Yep, I also decided to literally translate it, cover with tests and reimplement from the scratch according the specification (tests) - as soon as I know I can rely on them. That way I will be able to relicense it, if I wish. Or will it be also a derived work?!

Comment: @zerkms: That is skirting along the edges of the grey area. To be really safe that you can re-license, you should someone else to write up the algorithm/specification for you.

Comment: Even specification? Ohh.... :-S Thanks

Comment: @zerkms: It is the edge of the grey area, because there are no effective means to wipe your knowledge of the C++ implementation from your memory.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau is right when he says "_... someone else to write up ..._".  In industries where such "clean room reimplementation" is common, there are explicit barriers to communication between the team that analyses the other thing, and the team that builds its alternative, with only the specification crossing the barrier.